# Mudi kanikkai at oppiliappan

Tags: culture

Namaskaram,

We are a south Indian brahmin family. As per our tradition, we have to give mudi kanikkai thrice for infants borne in our family after ayushyahomam. For my second daughter, We could not fulfill because of ashoucham and COVID circumstances. When the situation eased we completed the first kanikkai in our Kula temple.
The second one has to be given at Tirupathi. But due to nonavailability of tickets, We are planning to go to Oppiliappan temple. Can anyone have any contact there so that I can confirm the procedure there??

Comment: Hello! Welcome to our site .. Right now the question has certain words that can not be understood by all. If you can give English words for them it would be helpful.

Comment: Namaskaram Mr Sivasankaran, meetups or connecting with one another on personal matters is against this site's policies. Please check out this site about the Oppiliappan Temple https://temple.dinamalar.com/en/new_en.php?id=426 Two phone numbers are also provided.